# @Entity is not creating a Table in my database in Spring

Tags: database, spring, postgresql

I have this class User in my Spring project

```
@Entity
public class User extends TimeStampModel{
    // Extends TimeStampModel so we know when the user was created
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String username;

    @Column
    private String password;

    @Column
    private long amountOfLikes;

    @Column
    private long amountOfDislikes;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Comment> comments;

    public User(){}

    //getters and setters omitted
}
```

But I am a getting a error: `Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "comment" does not exist` along with many other errors. All my other tables are getting created correctly. 
[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Here's my comment class, Likeable is an abstract class which has Columns for numberOfLikes and numberOfDislikes.

```
@Entity
public class Comment extends Likeable {
    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Lob
    private String text;

    @OneToOne
    private User author;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Comment> childComments;

    public Comment(){}

    //getters and setters omitted
}
```

Here's also the Likeable abstract class if necessary

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Likeable extends TimeStampModel{
    @Column
    private int likeAmount;

    @Column
    private int dislikeAmount;

    public void increaseLikeAmount(){
        this.likeAmount++;
    }
    public void increaseDislikeAmount(){
        this.dislikeAmount--;
    }

    //getters and setters omitted
}
```

Here are my application.properties also

```
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Test
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Comment: can you show us your `Comment` entity class?

Comment: set show-sql=true and share the table creation logs

Comment: @user404 added comment class to my post

Comment: @shubham should I just paste the whole log here or are there some special parts that you're interested in?

Comment: User is a reserved word in PostgreSQL. Simply modify the table name with ```@Table``` annotation on user entity.

Comment: @zforgo I was looking at a list of SQL reserved words, and user wasn't on it. I wasn't aware postrgreSQL has its own list of reserved words. Changed the User to something else and everything works now, massive thanks.

Comment: @randomboiguyhere as I said it is reserved word in PostgreSQL not in SQL standard. Unfortunately there are a lot of vendor specific reserved keywords. How to handle theese take a look at this very detailed blog entry: https://vladmihalcea.com/escape-sql-reserved-keywords-jpa-hibernate/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User is a reserved word in PostgreSQL, changing it to something else fixed everything.

Answer (score 2):

In your User entity, you are doing `@OneToMany` relation to Comment but in your Comment entity it is `@OneToOne.` Change it to `@ManyToOne.`

Comment: Ahh, didn't notice that, I changed it to @ManyToOne but that didn't fix it, table is still not getting created.

Comment: @randomboiguyhere share the full table creation logs.

Comment: @randomboiguyhere,  please share your whole error log

Answer (score 0):

Did you set hbm2ddl.auto to create for it to create tables, also you may need to add the mapping for your entity classes.

Comment: Yes, I will add my application.properties to the post now too.

Answer (score 0):

I see some problems in your code.

a) Your mapping is not correct. In User you have 1 to many mapping with comments while in comment you have one to one mapping with user. This needs to be rectified.
b) Please try using @Table over top of both user and comment class to rename your table names as user is a keyword. It will not work without that.

You may also want to use mappedby attribute with bidirectional mapping to prevent unnecessary columns.